# How to change the style precedence from incoming non-emotion css in emotion/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion

I'm creating a package using `@emotion/react` as its CSS styling library and will be given to people who may not use the styling library. [As described per their documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#style-precedence) incoming non-emotion classNames will be appended to the end of the style list and not take precedence. A CSS prop is the only way for parent components to apply styling.

This isn't ideal for me as I want the user to be able to define their own class and not have to revert to the CSS prop.

Currently, this is my implementation:

```
 <h1 css={css(defaults.h1, { color: theme.h1 }, { ...defTheme?.overrides?.h1?.props.css })}
 >
  {currentBlog?.title.text}
</h1>
```

That works... okay.

However, in the user-defined object that will be passed in as a theme, you must use the `css` prop that must use camelCased styles, for example:

```
  const theme: DefTheme = {
    theme: isDarkMode ? 'DARK_THEME' : 'LIGHT_THEME',
    overrides: {
      h1: { props: { css: { color: 'blue' } } },
    },
  };
```

As the user may use other ways of styling such as TailwindCSS, vanilla CSS, etc. I want the user to be able to define a class and pass it via a prop, for example:

```
  const theme: DefTheme = {
    theme: isDarkMode ? 'DARK_THEME' : 'LIGHT_THEME',
    overrides: {
      h2: {
        props: { className: 'bg-red-500' },
      },
    },
  };
```

And in turn, I would need to this:

```
      <h1
        css={css(defaults.h1, { color: theme.h1 })}
        className={defTheme?.overrides?.h1?.props.className}
      >
        {currentBlog?.title.text}
      </h1>
```

Although this className does allow users to style the element, it does *not* override any of the default styles and is not ideal at all! :(

Edit: I have tried using `@emotion/cache` and following a [sandbox that I found online](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-stonebraker-x3jr23?file=/src/App.js:741-745) but it still will not fix my problem

How can I fix this?